# Compare bytes in Python 2 from file with hex literal?

Tags: python, byte

I'm trying to write a script to see if a given file has a Java classfile header, i.e. the first 4 bytes of the file are 0xCAFEBABE.

However I'm not quite sure how to perform the equality checks.

Here's my current scratch code:

```
class JavaClassParser(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        if not os.path.isfile(self.filename):
            print "Please supply a valid source path"
            sys.exit(1)

        with open(self.filename, 'rb') as f:
            self.data = f.read()

        self.verify_header()

    def verify_header(self):
        """ Verifies 0xCAFEBABE header present
            (Java class file header) """
        header = struct.unpack("cccc", self.data[:4])
        if header != 0xCAFEBABE:
            print "File", self.filename, "does not appear to be a valid" +\
                " Java classfile. Header was", repr(header), "expected", repr(0xCAFEBABE)
            sys.exit(1)
```

When I feed it a valid Java classfile, I receive:

```
File myclass.class does not appear to be a valid Java classfile. Header was ('\xca', '\xfe', '\xba', '\xbe') expected 3405691582
```

So `0xCAFEBABE` is being interpreted as an int by Python -- I feel like I have a critical misunderstanding of something here.

I could rewrite `0xCAFEBABE` as `"\xca\xfe\xba\xbe"` and remove the `pack` call, but I find that syntax ugly. Is there a way I could get this working with the `0xCAFEBABE` literal?

Comment: In Python 3, you could remove the `pack` call and compare to `bytes.fromhex("CAFEBABE")`, if you like that better...

Comment: I do like that, but I'm using Python 2. Updated question to specify.

Comment: As an aside, do you really need to read the entire file? `f.read(4)` is sufficient to read the signature.

Comment: @tdelaney I am going to be doing other stuff on the rest of the file eventually -- you're right though, maybe I should persist the file handle on `self` and only read what I need to when I need to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a different argument to `unpack`:

```
>>> header = "\xca\xfe\xba\xbe"
>>> struct.unpack(">L", header)
(3405691582,)
>>> struct.unpack(">L", header)[0] == 0xcafebabe
True
```

According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-strings), `L` stands for "unsigned long" (i.e. 4 bytes), and `>` stands for big-endian (which is the format of these bytes).

Answer (score 1):

how bout just

```
self.data[:4].encode("hex") == "cafebabe"
```

or

```
self.data[:4] == "CAFEBABE".decode("hex")
```

(note I think its only py2)